# Find a parametric vector equation for $x - 1 = \frac{y+2}{2} = z$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a parametric vector equation for $x-1=\frac{y+2}2=z$ 
I have $z=\frac12(y+2)$ and $x=\frac12(y+4)$ but I am not sure how to put it in the form that is intended.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$x-1=\frac{y+2}2=z=t$$
We split this up into 3 equations in terms of $t$.

- $x-1+1=t+1$
- $x=t+1$
- $2\frac{y+2}2=y+2=2t$
- $y+2-2=2t-2$
- $y=2t-2$
- $z=t$

To convert this into a parametric vector equation, simply take the coefficients of $t$ for the components of direction vector $v$, and what is added after for the components of point $r_0$.

- $x=(1)t+1$
- $y=2t-2$
- $z=(1)t+0$
- $v=(1,2,1),\quad r_0=(1,-2,0)$
  And so the equation $r-r_0=tv$ becomes
  $$r=r_0+tv$$
  $$r=(1,-2,0)+t(1,2,1)$$

Comment: How do you express it as a *parametric vector equation*?

Comment: Updated my solution.